# std::lock_guard with variadic templates

Tags: c++, thread-safety, variadic-templates

[It is not necessary to follow the links to understand the question].

I combined the implementation of the singleton pattern in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/11138311), together with the synchronized file writing of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33597665/11138311).

Then I wanted to see if the interface of `SynchronizedFile` could provide a variadic templated `write` method, but I couldn't figure out how to properly combine this with the `std::lock_guard`.

Below is a *non-working* example. In this case it doesn't work because (I think) the two threads manage to pump stuff into the buffer `i_buf` in a non-synchronized way, resulting in a garbled `LOGFILE.txt`.

If I put the `std::lock_guard` inside the general template of `write` then the program doesn't halt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

static const int N_LOOP_LENGTH{10};

// This class manages a log file and provides write method(s)
// that allow passing a variable number of parameters of different
// types to be written to the file in a line and separated by commas.
class SynchronizedFile {
public:
    static SynchronizedFile& getInstance()
    {
        static SynchronizedFile instance;
        return instance;
    }

private:
    std::ostringstream i_buf;
    std::ofstream i_fout;
    std::mutex _writerMutex;

    SynchronizedFile () {
        i_fout.open("LOGFILE.txt", std::ofstream::out);
    }

public:
    SynchronizedFile(SynchronizedFile const&) = delete;
    void operator=(SynchronizedFile const&)   = delete;

    template<typename First, typename... Rest>
    void write(First param1, Rest...param)
    {
        i_buf << param1 << ", ";
        write(param...);
    }

    void write()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_writerMutex);
        i_fout << i_buf.str() << std::endl;
        i_buf.str("");
        i_buf.clear();
    }
};

// This is just some class that is using the SynchronizedFile class
// to write stuff to the log file.
class Writer {
public:
    Writer (SynchronizedFile& sf, const std::string& prefix) 
        : syncedFile(sf), prefix(prefix) {}

    void someFunctionThatWritesToFile () {
        syncedFile.write(prefix, "AAAAA", 4343, "BBBBB", 0.2345435, "GGGGGG");
    }
private:
    SynchronizedFile& syncedFile;
    std::string prefix;
};

void thread_method()
{
  SynchronizedFile &my_file1 = SynchronizedFile::getInstance();
  Writer writer1(my_file1, "Writer 1:");
  for (int i = 0; i < N_LOOP_LENGTH; ++ i)
    writer1.someFunctionThatWritesToFile();
}

int main()
{
  std::thread t(thread_method);

  SynchronizedFile &my_file2 = SynchronizedFile::getInstance();
  Writer writer2(my_file2, "Writer 2:");
  for (int i = 0; i < N_LOOP_LENGTH; ++i)
    writer2.someFunctionThatWritesToFile();

  t.join();
  std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

How could I successfully combine these three ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program deadlocks because `write` calls itself recursively while still holding the lock.

Either use a [`std::recursive_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex) <strike>or release the lock after writing your data out but before calling `write`</strike>.
E: Unlocking doesn't do the job, I didn't think this through...

E: Or lock once and defer to another private method to do the write.

```
template<typename... Args>
void write(Args&&... args)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_writerMutex);
    _write(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
void _write(First&& param1, Rest&&... param) // private method
{
    i_buf << std::forward<First>(param1) << ", ";
    _write(std::forward<Rest>(param)...);
}

void _write()
{
    i_fout << i_buf.str() << std::endl;
    i_buf.clear();
}
```

Comment: Let me study the recursive_mutex (I am clearly new to working with threads). I didn't understand the positions that you are referring to in the second alternative. And you answered it already.

Comment: @user647486 I've added an example. For `std::recursive_mutex` the `unlock` wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Some of these ideas might help me solve the problem. However, let me tell you that it looks like the first one with `unique_lock` didn't. I think it is because the `std::endl` is in a part that is not "locked". Some lines in the file get printed concatenated or after a couple of newline characters. Let me try the `recursive_mutex` approach.

Comment: The `recursive_mutex` approach does make it work properly. Thank you. I didn't know about it.